# query malformed, no start_object after query name

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

I am running this query against AWS Elasticsearch 5.1 and getting a malformed query error. Here is the body of the request. I am basically just checking if the field exists during the time range.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gt": "2017-03-21T15:37:08.595919Z",
                  "lte": "2017-04-21T15:52:08.595919Z"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "query": [
                {
                  "query_string": {
                    "query": "_exists_: $event.supplier"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The second `must` statement was incorrect:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gt": "2017-03-21T15:37:08.595919Z",
                  "lte": "2017-04-21T15:52:08.595919Z"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "_exists_: $event.supplier"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: where on the earth the second must statement is?

Comment: Having diffed the answer, they've removed the `query` specifier that used to be around `query_string`

Comment: For those coming here in the future: The `must` is an array, so the second set of curly braces that holds the `query_string` is the second `must`.

Comment: so it was the second item in the must array

Comment: @tar there is nothing to explain. The original query was malformed, which means that there was a syntax error in it. No error in the logic of the query of how it was created, just a syntax error. I've corrected the error and posted the correct query. If you compare the two you'll notice the difference. Downvoting a correct answer with an explanation like that is unfair. I hope you'll find my other answers on the Elasticsearch subject more useful to you.

Comment: @AndreiStefan can you also explain the error "no start_object after query name", what on earth does it mean?  in this case what exactly is a "start_object" and what are the possible things/keywords that could be a start_object?

Comment: @ThomasNguyen in JSON format `{ }` is considered an "object". Start of an object is the opening curly bracket. `no start_object after query name` means the JSON parser is expecting an opening curly bracket after the "query name".